# @IBOutletと、Viewに複数のボタンを結びつけた時のアクションの管理について

Tags: swift, ios, storyboard

UIButtonのアクションの管理の仕方について質問をさせていただきます。
つかぬ事をお聞きしてしまうかもしれないのですが、どなたか回答いただけたら幸いです。

---

```
@IBOutlet weak var button_0: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button_1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button_2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button_3: UIButton!
//...以下複数個続く
```

と複数個のUIButtonをViewControllerなどに結びつけて
それぞれのボタンのアクションを設定したい場合

```
var buttons:[UIButton] = []
```

と配列などを用意して管理するViewControllerのViewDidLoadなどで

```
buttons.append(button_0)
buttons.append(button_1)
buttons.append(button_2)
//...以下個数分続く
for i in 0..<buttons.count{
    buttons[i].tag = i
    buttons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(ToolView.action(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
```

と記述するのは単調であまり良くない気がしてしまうのですが なにか良い方法はありますか？
やはり、複数個の部品の設置はコードから作成するほうが良いのでしょうか？

※ViewControllerのactionはこのような感じで使おうと思っています...

```
@objc private func action(sender: UIButton){
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        print("button_0")
    case 1:
        print("button_1")
    case 2:
        print("button_2")
    //...個数分続く
    default:break
    }
}
```

---

---

---

おかげさまで解決しました。
quesera2さん、画像付きでとても分かりやすかったです。ありがとうございます。
Le Pere d'OOさんも当日の深夜に返していただき、助かりました。ありがとうございます。

よく調べればもしかしたら出てきた質問だったかもしれませんが、私自身初めて知ることができたので良かったです。
@IBOutlet Collectionの記事
[はじはじアプリ体験記](http://hajihaji-lemon.com/smartphone/swift/outlet-collection/)さん
[スタック・オーバーフロー](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052459/swift-iboutletcollection-equivalent)

Answer (score 3):

Storyboard とコードの `@IBOutlet` を紐付けるときに、`Outlet Collection` を指定すると、配列型で複数の View を紐付けることができます。

[image: Outlet Collection]

ですが、この場合はひとつの `@IBAction` に複数のボタンを直接紐付けるのが早いと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`@IBOutlet` は 1:1 である必要がありますが、`@IBAction` は 1:n の紐付けを行うことができます。`sender.tag` でボタンを識別する方法でうまく動作します。

```
@IBAction func action(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        print("button_0")
    case 1:
        print("button_1")
    case 2:
        print("button_2")
    //...個数分続く
    default:break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swiftでは、

```
@IBOutlet var buttons:[UIButton] = []
```

のように配列型で`@IBOutlet`のプロパティを宣言しておくことで、複数の`UIButton`を1つのプロパティに結びつけることができます。あなたの例にあるような個別の`button_0`...を宣言して自前で`buttons.append(button_0)`とする必要はありません。

エディターをアシスタントエディターモードにして、コード側の`@IBOutlet`の前の黒ポチから、Interface Builder側の`UIButton`に(繰り返し)つないでいくのが簡単だと思います。

やってみれば大したことではないのがすぐにわかるかと思うので、お試しください。